# PySpark: How to filter on multiple columns coming from a list?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that will get filtered (not null) on multiple columns. These columns are coming from a config file.
Lets say I have a config file that has `filterCols: COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2...,COLUMN_10`.
In my code I can hardcode the column names like:

```
df = dataDF.filter(~col("COLUMN_1").isNull() & 
                   ~col("COLUMN_2").isNull() &
                   ......
                   ~col("COLUMN_10").isNull())
```

But these columns can be removed, as and when required, or more columns can be added as well.
If I follow the above approach, I will have to change and deploy the code every time.

Is there a way where I can loop over these columns and then filter?
I tried something like this:

```
colList = ['COLUMN_1', 'COLUMN_2', ...,'COLUMN_10']
df = dataDF
for name in colList:
    df = df.filter(~col(name).isNull())
```

But `df` is showing zero records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate a query string based on your columns and use SparkSQL.

Example:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
columns = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
df.createTempView("table")
df = spark.sql(
    "SELECT * FROM table WHERE {}".format(
        " AND ".join(x + " IS NOT NULL" for x in columns)
    )
)
```

Result:

```
+---+---+---+---+                                                               
|a  |b  |c  |d  |
+---+---+---+---+
|1  |2  |3  |4  |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 4):

Use python `functools.reduce` to chain multiple conditions:

```
from functools import reduce
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


filter_expr = reduce(lambda a, b: a & b, [F.col(c).isNotNull() for c in colList])

df = df.filter(filter_expr)
```